# Debug c++ process started by c# program

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have 2 projects in solution. C# program whitch start new process (c++ program). I want to be able debuging c++ program. I found this code.

```
        public static void Attach(this System.Diagnostics.Process process)
    {
        System.Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
        EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        int tryCount = 5;
        while (tryCount --> 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Processes processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses;
                foreach (EnvDTE.Process proc in processes.Cast<EnvDTE.Process>().Where(
                  proc => proc.Name.IndexOf(process.ProcessName) != -1))
                {
                    proc.Attach();
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format
                    ("Attached to process {0} successfully.", process.ProcessName));
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            catch (COMException)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

The debuger is attaded but in c++ project are errors

> “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.”

I have Enabled native code debuging

Comment: Is your c++ project being built into the directory the c# project is running from (most likely the c# debug directory)?

Comment: It wasn't. I've set same build directory in both projects but still it dont work.